# How do you convert a Date into a ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone with a particular timezone?

Tags: ruby, timezone, activesupport

I have a Date object like this:

```
>> the_date
=> Tue, 12 Jun 2012

>> the_date.class
=> Date
```

And a timezone stored as a string:

```
>> tz = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
=> "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
```

And I'm looking to generate an ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone at midnight of the given date in the given timezone (*not* midnight of the given date in utc, then converted to the given timezone). The best way I've found to do this so far is exceedingly ugly:

```
>> the_time = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new(tz).parse(the_date.to_s)
=> Tue, 12 Jun 2012 00:00:00 PDT -07:00

>> the_time.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

There's got to be a better way to generate this! Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Not really much better, but different than your solution:

```
the_date.to_time.in_time_zone
#=> Mon, 11 Jun 2012 22:00:00 UTC +00:00

the_date.to_time.in_time_zone(tz)
#=> Mon, 11 Jun 2012 15:00:00 PDT -07:00

Time.zone = tz
#=> "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"

the_date.to_time.in_time_zone
#=> Mon, 11 Jun 2012 15:00:00 PDT -07:00

the_date.to_time.in_time_zone.end_of_day
#=> Mon, 11 Jun 2012 23:59:59 PDT -07:00

(the_date.to_time.in_time_zone + 1.day).beginning_of_day
#=> Tue, 12 Jun 2012 00:00:00 PDT -07:00
```